# How do I get "href" value of an "a" tag using scaper in Rust?

Tags: web-scraping, rust, href, rust-cargo

I have a Rust project that used the "scraper" library.
I want to get the href value of an a tag element from a website.
It is not shown in the documentation how to do it.
I tried the below code but it only returned the inner HTML content.

```
let result_sites: scraper::Selector =
        scraper::Selector::parse("a.s-topbar--logo").unwrap();
```

What is the best way to get the href value?

Comment: https://docs.rs/scraper/latest/scraper/node/struct.Element.html#method.attr

Comment: @BallpointBen I tried using result_sites.attr("href) but it did not work._

Comment: How didn't it work? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman yes I got the error message "no method named `attr` found for struct `Selector` in the current scope method not found in `Selector`rustcClick for full compiler diagnostic" on hover in VS code.

Comment: You need to actually select the nodes from the document, having a `Selector` by itself is not enough.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman how do you do that?

Comment: Look in the crate examples and see if you can find by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use scraper::{Html, Selector};

let html = r#"..."#;
let fragment = Html::parse_fragment(html);
let sites_selector = Selector::parse("a.s-topbar--logo").unwrap();

for el in fragment.select(&sites_selector) {
    let href = el.value().attr("href").unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", href);
}
```

[Here is the documentation with example](https://docs.rs/scraper/0.17.1/scraper/#accessing-element-attributes)

Comment: I got the error message "no method named `next` found for struct `ElementRef<'_>` in the current scoperustcClick for full compiler diagnostic"

Comment: `next()` wasn't needed. It should work now.

Comment: Thanks, I changed "values" to "value" and it's working now.